# How to identify the iOS version in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In native iOS I know how to get device iOS version. But now I want to achieve in `Xamarin.iOS`. So,

how can I get the iOS version of device using `Xamarin.iOS`?

Comment: Did you check on Xamarin Documentation? http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/projects/environment_checks/

Comment: Thanks, I checked it!!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I am able to get the iOS device version using

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(7, 0)
```

The above method returns the BOOL value true, if the device version is above (or equal to) iOS 7. Otherwise it returns false.

Answer (score 4):

Even if this is too late but it might helps somebody else. You can get the iOS version, running on your device, in your Xamarin.iOS project(in AppDelegate.cs) this way:

```
string targetOS = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion;

Debug.WriteLine("iOS version: ", targetOS); // =In my case=> iOS version: 12.4.4
```

Xamarin.Forms version 4.3.0

Comment: This answer is better in my opinion