# Cross compatible differences xamarin / C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, code-behind

hope you can help!

Wondering how I can change code based on device version?

For example I have skia sharp code with a size integer set as below:

```
int size = Math.Min(180, 180);
```

On ios 13 this looks good but on ios 11 it's way too big!

How can I change the code behind size integer based on the ios version?

Thanks!

Comment: I highly doubt your issue has anything to do with iOS version, but it is rather tied to screen density and/or scale that your code doesn't account for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59705470/how-can-i-find-out-android-and-ios-versions-when-running-a-xamarin-forms-applica

Answer (score 1):

##### For iOS

Just simply use `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13,0)` .

It equals to `@available(iOS 13, *)` in Objective-C .

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21263587/8187800.

##### For forms

You can take a look at [Xamarin.Essentials: Device Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios) .

```
// Operating System Version Number (7.0)
var version = DeviceInfo.VersionString;
```

Comment: I have an error trying to use this as it says UIDevice is not available in the current context, using 'Device' instead but  then then methid isn't available on this...

Comment: I've also tried 'Version version = new Version(ObjCRuntime.Constants.Version);' but ObjCRuntime doesn't exist in context either - do I need a namespace that isn't mentioned?

Comment: `ObjCRuntime` is the exact namespace which is included in Xamarin.iOS , check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/objcruntime?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12 . Have you tried my way ?Does it work or not ?

Comment: I have, "UIDevice is not recognised"so Intellisense recommends to us Android.Hardward.Usb or Android.Bluetooth.Bluetooth class - I don't this this method works for the latest SDK 5.0.403?

Comment: I found this but it doesn't specify version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I thought you're coding in iOS project , the code above is used in iOS project , for forms you can use var version = DeviceInfo.VersionString;  , which is included in [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios) plugin .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the iOS version and based on it you can set the value accordingly.

```
string version = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion;

if(version == ……….
```

Comment: I have an error trying to use this as it says UIDevice is not available in the current context, using 'Device' instead but  then then methid isn't available on this...

Comment: I've also tried 'Version version = new Version(ObjCRuntime.Constants.Version);' but ObjCRuntime doesn't exist in context either - do I need a namespace that isn't mentioned?