# How can I make a condition based on iOS version in c#?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have an iOS application that is written with xamarin iOS.
The problem I have is that the navbar stopped working since iOS version 13 when they(apple) changed how it behaves.

Now, I have found a solution for it, but that code should only apply to devices with iOS version 13 and greater.

So my question is, how do I in C# set a condition to check if a device have a certain iOS version?

I know you can type something like this:

```
#if __iOS__
 //code here
#endif
```

But that only checks if it's an iOS device and not what version it is. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Does your solution works on older versions ?

Comment: Does it need to be a symbol or is a normal if-statement alright?

Comment: @PtitXav No it does not, I downloaded an older version just to try but it crashes since the new changes that were implementet for ios 13+ doesn't exist with that OS version.

It's the UINavigationBarAppearance that were introduced to 13+

Comment: @TheTanic Not quite sure to be honest with you! Do you have an example with a normal if-statment?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21263587/3888657

Comment: @TheTanic Thank you! Seems to have done the trick!